# Instana installation using Helm to monitor Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, microk8s, instana

I am stuck on instlling Instana using help to monitor my K8s.

Here is the commands that I am using for this:

1. `kubectl create namespace instana-agent`
2. helm install instana-agent    --repo https://agents.instana.io/helm    --namespace instana-agent    --create-namespace    --set agent.key=KEY    --set agent.downloadKey=KEY    --set agent.endpointHost=ingress-coral-saas.instana.io    --set agent.endpointPort=443    --set cluster.name='matt-helm-1212'    --set zone.name='US-1'    instana-agent

After that, I run this command:

`kubectl get all -n instana-agent`

At this stage I am stuck, the Instana is stuck to be created and status is remained as "Pneding" all time.

NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/instana-agent-6qw8d   0/2     Pending   0          17m

I am using the following helm version:

version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.11.0", GitCommit:"472c5736ab01133de504a826bd9ee12cbe4e7904", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.18.10"}

I waited so long for my Instana agent to be appeard and it never happened. I tried to have a Linux agent and it works however this problem is related to only K8S clusters.

I would like to also add that I am using EC2 machine and microk8s to run K8s clusters.

Please let me know if you require further informaiton.

I tried installing Instana using Helm and I was expecting to see my Instana agent on the Instana agent. It will not be appeard. Instead this is what I see when I check my Instana namespace:

NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/instana-agent-6qw8d   0/2     Pending   0          17m

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like with your k8s cluster more than the instana-agent deployment.

Try to get more logs by  describe the pending pod or describe the events in instana-agent naspace.

```
kubectl get event --sort-by .metadata.creationTimestamp -n instana-agent
```

```
kubectl describe pod -l app.kubernetes.io/name=instana-agent -n instana-agent
```

Once the instana-agent pods are up and running, get agent logs by :

```
kubectl logs -l app.kubernetes.io/name=instana-agent -n instana-agent -c instana-agent
```

Answer (score -1):

Forgot to add the script :-)..

https://support.instana.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006773992-How-to-get-Instana-agent-logs-for-a-Kubernetes-namespace

Comment: Please use the edit link to update your answer instead of posting a new one. You really need to read through the [tour] and the help center. SO is no customer support platform. Answers here need to stand on their own and need to fully answer the question. Instructions how to debug and a contact address aren't enough.

Comment: can you elaborate?